# C# LINQ Custom Order By

Tags: c#, linq

I am having issues determining whether I can use LINQ to do some custom sorting on the class or whether I need to do the sorting manually.

I have the following classes :-

```
public class Opportunity : BaseEntity {

[Key]
public int OpportunityID { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<OpportunityProduct> OpportunityProducts { get; set;}

}

public class OpportunityProduct : BaseEntity {

[Key]
public int OpportunityProductID { get; set; }
public SaleType SaleType { get; set; }
public decimal SaleValue { get;set;} 

}
```

I would like to return a list of Opportunities sorted by the sum of their OpportunityProducts such as :-

```
var opportunities = opportunities.OrderBy( o => o.OpportunityProducts.xxx).ToList();
```

An opportunity can have a number of opportunityproducts and the "value" of an OpportunityProduct differs based on the SaleType.

An example of this is as follows:-

```
//Rental Products
var rentalValue = SaleValue * 12;

//Purchase Products
var saleValue = SaleValue;
```

An opportunity can also have multiple different types of OpportunityProducts aka an opportunity may have a Sale as one OpportunityProduct and a Rental as another Opportunity Product.

The sorting is by the Total Value of the ICollection aka the sum of each individual OpportunityProduct.

Thanks,

Comment: Is this C# LINQ or SQL LINQ? In C# you can afford to run any function in your `OrderBy` method to calculate a numeric (or otherwise comparable) value for each item in the enumerable. If it's a SQL LINQ, then you're limited to what Entity Framework can translate into a SQL statement, in which case most complex calculations won't fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The sorting is by the Total Value of the `ICollection` aka the sum of each individual `OpportunityProduct`.

Then you need `Sum(...)` in your `OrderBy`:

```
var orderedOpportunities = opportunities
    .OrderByDescending( o => o.OpportunityProducts.Sum(p => p.SaleValue))
    .ToList();
```

Use of `OrderByDescending` would prioritize highest opportunities to the beginning of the list.

Note that this approach assumes that all opportunity products are applicable at the same time, i.e. you can sell *and* rent the item at the same time. If this is not the case, use `Max` instead of `Sum`:

```
var orderedOpportunities = opportunities
    .OrderByDescending( o => o.OpportunityProducts.Max(p => p.SaleValue))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This wont work as the SaleValue may need a calculation to be performed.  If it is a Purchase then the above would work, but if the SaleType is a Rental the value needs to be calculated as SaleValue * 12.

Comment: @DeaconKelly You can use a conditional inside `Max`/`Sum`, i.e. instead of writing `p => p.SaleValue` you could write `p => (p.SaleType==Rental ? 12 : 1) * p.SaleValue`

Comment: To clarify :- OpportunityProduct 1 is a sale with SaleValue $10000.  OpportunityProduct 2 is a rental with SaleValue of $1000.  So the total value of the Opportunity is ($10000 + ($1000 * 12) ) = $22000.  This is the value to OrderBy